# What does "()" stand for in: val f = {() => x += 1}

Tags: scala

My question is about Scala function:

```
var x = 1
val f = {() => x += 1}
```

It's clear if the function literal looks like:

```
val f = (x:Int)=>x+1
```

But what does `()` stand for in:

```
val f = {() => x += 1}
```

I am pretty new in Scala.
I've read out the function chapter in a Scala book already, but still cannot understand what `()` means here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr** It's just an empty argument list of a function.

It's an empty argument list. It means you're not passing any arguments to the function. So normally that kind of function would not *consume* any value, but would *supply* value when it's called.

Your case is special. Variable `x` comes from the outer scope and is bound to your function so it becomes closure. Every time you invoke `f` it will change the value of `x`.

Comment: The code comes from: [link](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/basics.html)
class C {
 var acc = 0
 def minc = { acc += 1 }
 val finc = { () => acc += 1 }
}
The purpose is to distinguish method from function.
Any situation we need to define a function with an empty argument list?

Sorry I am still learning how to edit the code indentedly.

Comment: You would create function when you want to `supply/produce` some value whenever a function is called or as in your case if you want to change the value of the variable bounded to the closure function.

Comment: Check out this [article](https://data-flair.training/blogs/scala-closures/) about closures.

Answer (score 6):

The `()` in the `val f = {() => x += 1}` represents the function takes no argument and increase value of x by 1

it is similar to

```
var x = 1
def foo(): Unit = {
    x += 1
}


val f: () => Unit = () => x += 1
```

This is not a pure function

Comment: Page robot told me not to say thank in comment. Txxxks.

Comment: in Stackoverflow instead of saying thanks you should: if this solved your question - you should 'accept' it and mark it as useful (+1)

Answer (score 2):

`f` is of type `() => Unit`. A function that takes no arguments and returs nothing (Unit)

```
val f: () => Unit = {() => x += 1}
```

The java equivalent of this would be the [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) interface.